# Facebook Direct Messages for Mobile Devices Options

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Now that Facebook rolled out their new policy in February 2013 where, among other changes, apps cannot post on friend's wall; and Send Dialog is not supported for Mobile Devices.

What options do we have to post on a user's friend wall (on behave of the user already authenticated with an app) using mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can use feed dialog or redirect the user to a mobile friendly url by adding *display=touch* and *to=FRIENDS_ID* and show a dialog box.

```
To display a mobile-friendly Feed Dialog, redirect the user to the following URL:
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&to=FRIENDS_ID&display=touch
```

Using feed dialog and javascript api

```
function postToFeed(kompis) {
    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: 'http://url.nu',
      link: 'http://www.url.se',
      picture: 'http://url/tfc.gif',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.',
      display:'touch',
      to:kompis
    };
    function callback(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
     alert('Post was published.');
     document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
      } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
      }
    }
    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```

ps: when I try it in firefox I set my User Agent to "iphone" otherwise it  would'nt work!

Answer (score -2):

open facebook app.first open your account.open yuor profile.edit your number.ok the option 'get notifications by sms'.save the options.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming problems... the question refers to the API, not the user interface.